# glmnet model performance compared to boosting algorithms

Tags: r, machine-learning, glmnet

To help learn about machine learning I am coding up some examples, not to show that one method is better than another, but to illustrate how to use various functions and what parameters to tune.  I started with [this blog](https://www.r-craft.org/r-news/boost-series-i-advantage-in-smooth-functions/) that compared BooST and xgboost, then I successfully added gbm to the example.  Now I am trying to add glmnet, but the model returned alwyas has (near) zero for both of the coefficients.  Either I am doing something wrong, or glmnet is just not the correct algo for this data.  I am trying to figure out which it is.  Here is my reproducible example:

```
# Uncomment the following 2 lines if you need to install BooST (requires devtools)
#library(devtools)
#install_github("gabrielrvsc/BooST")

library(BooST)
library(xgboost)
library(gbm)
library(glmnet)

# Data generating process
dgp = function(N, r2){
  X = matrix(rnorm(N*2,0,1),N,2)
  X[,ncol(X)] = base::sample(c(0,1),N,replace=TRUE)
  aux = X
  yaux = cos(pi*(rowSums(X)))
  vyaux = var(yaux)
  ve = vyaux*(1-r2)/r2
  e = rnorm(N,0,sqrt(ve))
  y = yaux+e
  return(list(y = y, X = X))
}

# Real data
x1r = rep(seq(-4,4,length.out = 1000), 2)
x2r = c(rep(0,1000), rep(1,1000))
yr = cos(pi*(x1r+x2r))
real_function = data.frame(x1 = x1r, x2 = as.factor(x2r), y = yr)

# Train data (noisy)
set.seed(1)
data = dgp(N = 1000, r2 = 0.5)
y = data$y
x = data$X

# Test data (noisy)
set.seed(2)
dataout=dgp(N = 1000, r2 = 0.5)
yout = dataout$y
xout = dataout$X

# Set seed and train all 4 models
set.seed(1)
BooST_Model = BooST(x, y, v = 0.18, M = 300 , display = TRUE)
xgboost_Model = xgboost(x, label = y, nrounds = 300, params = list(eta = 0.14, max_depth = 2))
gbm_Model = gbm.fit(x, y, distribution = "gaussian", n.trees = 10000, shrinkage = .001, interaction.depth=5)
glmnet_Model = cv.glmnet(x, y, family = "gaussian", alpha=0)
coef(glmnet_Model)
```

> coef(glmnet_Model)
>
> 3 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
>                                                              1
>
> (Intercept)  0.078072154632597062784427066617354284971952438
>
> V1          -0.000000000000000000000000000000000000003033534
>
> V2          -0.000000000000000000000000000000000000044661342

```
# Predict from test data
p_BooST = predict(BooST_Model, xout)
p_xgboost = predict(xgboost_Model, xout)
p_gbm = predict(gbm_Model, xout, n.trees=10000)
p_glmnet = predict(glmnet_Model, xout)

# Show RMSE
sqrt(mean((p_BooST - yout)^2))
sqrt(mean((p_xgboost - yout)^2))
sqrt(mean((p_gbm - yout)^2))
sqrt(mean((p_glmnet - yout)^2))

fitted = data.frame(x1 = x[,1], x2 = as.factor(x[,2]),
  BooST = fitted(BooST_Model),
  xgboost = predict(xgboost_Model, x),
  gbm = predict(object = gbm_Model, newdata = x, n.trees = 10000),
  glmnet = predict(glmnet_Model, newx = x, s=glmnet_Model$lambda.min)[, 1], y = y)

# Plot noisy Y
ggplot() + geom_point(data = fitted, aes(x = x1, y = y, color = x2)) + geom_line(data = real_function, aes(x = x1, y = y, linetype = x2))

# Plot xgboost
ggplot() + geom_point(data = fitted, aes(x = x1, y = y), color = "gray") + geom_point(data = fitted, aes(x = x1, y = xgboost, color = x2)) + geom_line(data = real_function, aes(x = x1, y = y, linetype = x2))

# Plot BooST
ggplot() + geom_point(data = fitted, aes(x = x1, y = y), color = "gray") + geom_point(data = fitted, aes(x = x1, y = BooST, color = x2)) + geom_line(data = real_function, aes(x = x1, y = y, linetype = x2))

# Plot gbm
ggplot() + geom_point(data = fitted, aes(x = x1, y = y), color = "gray") + geom_point(data = fitted, aes(x = x1, y = gbm, color = x2)) + geom_line(data = real_function, aes(x = x1, y = y, linetype = x2))

# Plot glmnet
ggplot() + geom_point(data = fitted, aes(x = x1, y = y), color = "gray") + geom_point(data = fitted, aes(x = x1, y = glmnet, color = x2)) + geom_line(data = real_function, aes(x = x1, y = y, linetype = x2))
```

Comment: Since, as you say, your issue is with the coefficients, please update your question to include them explicitly, and possibly explain why you think these values are problematic...

Comment: Also, as a general principle, lines of code that are commented out should not be included here (they are of no use, and they only create noise - edited & removed).

Comment: Those comments were to help someone install the BooST package since it is not on CRAN, making the example easier for others to run.  The zero coefficients are a problem because it does a terrible job of replicating the cosine fucntion, whereas the other three methods do a pretty good job of replicating the cosine function.

Comment: I wanted to keep my code example short, but if you want a visual, here are plots of all four methods.  You will see that the glmnet plot looks much different than the other plots.   The question is, can the glmnet model be improved?

Comment: You have a point, I restored the commented lines with an explanatory comment; as for the coefficients, I still cannot *see* them (without running your code, that is)...

Comment: OK, I run your code - you don't do anything wrong, beyond the fact that you are trying to compare glmnet with some *much more* powerful algorithms...

Answer (score 1):

> Either I am doing something wrong

You are not, at least programming-wise

> or glmnet is just not the correct algo for this data

It is not that glmnet is "not correct" (although it is supposed to be primarily used for problems with *a lot* of predictors, not just a couple); it is that your comparison is fundamentally "unfair" and not appropriate: all the other 3 algorithms you use are *ensemble* ones - your `gbm`, for instance, consists of *ten thousand (10,000)* individual decision trees...! Attempting to compare *this* with a single regressor, such as glmnet, well, it is almost like comparing apples to oranges...

Nevertheless, this should be a good exercise & reminder that, the fact that all these tools, from a *programming* perspective, seem "equivalent" ("*well, I just use `library()` to load each of them, right? So, why they shouldn't be kind of equivalent and comparable?*"), hides *a lot*... And that's why at least an elementary familiarity with the principles of statistical learning is always a good idea (I strongly suggest the freely available [Introduction to Statistical Learning](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/%7Egareth/ISL/), for starters - including also R code snippets).

The ensemble method of [Adaboost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AdaBoost), in particular (which is the unifying element behind all the other 3 algorithms you are using here), is no joke! It was a *real game changer* when it came out (roughly 10 years before the era of deep learning), and, in the `xgboost` implementation, it is still the winning choice in most Kaggle competitions that involve "traditional" structured data (i.e. no text or images).

Answer (score 1):

Remember that glmnet fits a *linear* model, meaning the response can be written as a linear combination of the predictors:

```
 y = b0 + b1*x1 + b2*x2 + ...
```

In your dataset, you define the response as, variously

> ```
> yaux = cos(pi*(rowSums(X)))
>
> yr = cos(pi*(x1r+x2r))
> ```

which in both cases is clearly *not* a linear combination of the predictors.